# what difference does it make to append stylesheets or js files on different order? how to use append and prepend stylesheet or append and prependfile?

Tags: jquery, css, zend-framework

What difference does it make if I write:

```
$this->headScript()->prependFile( PUBLIC_PATH."/js/frontend/fb.js" );
```

And then this:

```
$this->headScript()->appendFile( PUBLIC_PATH."/js/jQuery.bPopup.js" );
```

Comment: result would be the same if both are appending the file into head tag.

Comment: You are appending JavaScript files, not stylesheets. Typo?

Comment: @UweB I have corrected it .appendFile() and prependfile() for js and appendStylesheet and prependStylesheet() for css

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`prependFile()` method adds the top of the list, and `appendFile()` method adds at the end of the list.

It is better to use `prependFile` for libraries like `jQuery` and `appendFile` for scripts that need these libraries

Answer (score 0):

CSS means Cascading style sheets. That means the style sheet at the bottom will have precedence than sheets above it (unless you use !important parameter) in case of conflict. Thus Appending will have precedence above pre-pending in case of conflict.

I don't know in the context of Zend framework but generally it works this way.